# Postmapping not working, gives 405 method not allowed error

Tags: java, spring-boot, post

So I've been following along with Java Brains' Spring Boot Quick Start course and I've come across a bit of an issue, the idea of it is to have courses related to a topic, such that your url reads ".../topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}" for any given course.

Most of my controller mappings are working correctly, however I'm having issues with POST and PUT (and probably DELETE but can't test it) where it's giving me the following error (I'm making requests using postman):

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2021-05-16T22:10:18.049+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/topics/chem/courses"
}
```

I've already made a POST request to "http://localhost:8080/topics" to add the chem topic, and it shows up when I do a GET, however if I try to POST to "http://localhost:8080/topics/chem/courses" it gives the above error.

My Controller is built like so:

```java
@RestController
public class CourseController {

    private final CourseService courseService;

    public CourseController(CourseService courseService) {
        this.courseService = courseService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/topics/{topicId}/courses")
    public List<Course> getAllCourses(@PathVariable String topicId) {
        return courseService.getCourses(topicId);
    }
    @GetMapping("/topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}")
    public Course getCourse(@PathVariable String topicId, @PathVariable String id) {
        return courseService.getCourse(id);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/topics/{topicId}/courses}")
    public void addCourse(@RequestBody Course course, @PathVariable String topicId) {
        course.setTopic(new Topic(topicId, "", ""));
        courseService.addCourse(course);
    }

    @PutMapping("/topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}")
    public void updateCourse(@RequestBody Course course, @PathVariable String topicId) {
        course.setTopic(new Topic(topicId, "", ""));
        courseService.updateCourse(course);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}")
    public void deleteCourse(@PathVariable String topicId, @PathVariable String id) {
        courseService.deleteCourse(id);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell there's no reason for it to be giving this error, if anyone has any insight into what's up it would be greatly appreciated, the Spring debug log is below as well in case that helps anyone:

[image]

Comment: Can you please check if there is any actual body that is sent as part of POST request?
As in method #addCourse there is argument '@RequestBody Course course' which implies that there should be a request body

Comment: @Daniel yep, header is marked with Content-type:application/json and then the body is trying to send {"id": "chem1", "name": "Chemistry 101", "description": "Chemistry 101 Desc"}